# Не могу найти синтаксическую ошибку Python либо использую что-то неправильно

Tags: python, discord.py, синтаксис

С целью изучения пайтон на практике, для бота в дискорде пытаюсь сделать команду которая должна выводить сообщение типа embed в чат, при этом пользователь сам вводит что он хочет видеть в этом сообщении

В теории пользователь должен ввести, к примеру:
`!!em 'Title': 'Заголовок', 'Desc': 'Текст'`
а затем всё, кроме команды, должно быть записано в виде массива (не в отдельном файле а просто в памяти во время компиляции) как-то так:

```py
embedCache {
'Title': 'Заголовок',
'Desc': 'Текст'
}
```

Вот сам код :

```py
@bot.command()
async def em(ctx, *, textE): #звёздочка в скобках указывает, что весь текст сообщения будет значением переменной textE
    embedCache = {eval(textE)}
    embedVar = discord.Embed(title=embedCache['Title'], description=embedCache['Desc'])
    await ctx.send(embed=embedVar)
```

Однако мне выдаёт синтаксическую ошибку в массиве на первой же строчке (не знаю какую конкретно, не указывается так как массив никуда не записывается)

скрин ошибки: (извините ввести ошибку не могу ибо она огромная я хз что из этого всего вам нужно а вводить, думаю, вы и сами задолбаетесь)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добавьте в вопрос полный текст ошибки

Comment: ``em(ctx, *, textE)`` - что означает звездочка в скобках?

Comment: Использование eval в таком месте - это очень плохо. Например, если у вас ненароком импортирован `os`, то пользователь, введя `os.system('...')`, может выполнить любую (!) команду, например, удалить все файлы на сервере, где это запущено, к которым пользователь, под которым бот запущен, имеет доступ. Если уж так нужно, то используйте `ast.literal_eval`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Текст `'Title': 'Заголовок', 'Desc': 'Текст'` не является синтаксически валидным кодом, поэтому и выводится ошибка. Вводите

`!!em {'Title': 'Заголовок', 'Desc': 'Текст'}`

или добавляйте скобки перед отправкой текста в `eval()`.